# Dipole-Coupling Tensor: Electrostatic Dipole Moments

Tags: vectors, physics, tensor-products, kronecker-symbol, electromagnetism

I've been struggling with this problem today.

[Here's an image of the question I'm attempting to answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMsGj.png)

I'm relatively new to tensor algebra (I've been studying it for about a week or two), and I've been able to solve most problems, except for this one. Here's some work:

$$
U = \frac{1}{r^3}\left(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{Q} - \dfrac{3(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{r})(\vec{Q}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^2}\right) \equiv \frac{1}{r^3}P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
\vec{P}\cdot\vec{Q} - \dfrac{3(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{r})(\vec{Q}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
$$
$$
P^ie_iQ^je_j- \dfrac{3(P^ie_i(Q^je_j - P^ie_i))(Q^je_j(Q^je_j - P^ie_i))}{(Q^je_j - P^ie_i)^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
$$
$$
P^ie_iQ^je_j- \dfrac{3P^ie_iQ^je_j(Q^je_j - P^ie_i)(Q^je_j - P^ie_i)}{(Q^je_j - P^ie_i)^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P^ie_iQ^je_j- \dfrac{3P^ie_iQ^je_j(Q^je_j - P^ie_i)^2}{(Q^je_j - P^ie_i)^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P^ie_iQ^je_j- 3P^ie_iQ^je_j = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
-2P^ie_iQ^je_j = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
-2(\delta^{ik}P_k)e_iQ^je_j = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_k(-2\delta^{ik})e_ie_jQ^j = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_k(-2\delta^{ik}\delta_{ij})Q^j = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_k(-2\delta^{k}_{j})Q^j = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_i(-2\delta^{i}_{j})Q^j = P_iT_j^iQ^j
$$
$$
\boxed{T^i_j = -2\delta^i_j}
$$

I'm not very confident that this is the correct answer. I feel as though I'm manipulating these tensors half-assed. Moreover, this answer does not appear to be very elegant; I wouldn't expect a coupling tensor to have this form (although perhaps if we replaced the kronecker delta with a metric tensor for curved space, I would be more compelled to believe it). In the last step, I changed indices because I believe you can do so with impunity.

Please let me know if you see any blatant errors that should *not* have been committed under **any** circumstances. I have found that doing independent studies with tensors has been the most difficult for me yet.

Comment: The main error is using the same summation index in different terms. For example: $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = a_i b_i$ however this does not mean that $(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})^2$ is $(a_i b_i)(a_ib_i)$ ($=\sum_i a_i^2 b_i^2$ which is wrong). The two summations are different so we must use a different index, say $j$, in the last term making it $(a_i b_i)(a_jb_j) \equiv \sum_i a_i b_i\sum_j a_j b_j$. Also you should not expand $r^2$ in terms of $Q$ and $P$ in the denominator. Keep it as it is. The final answer will be on the form $\delta^i_j - c \frac{r^i r_j}{r^2}$ where $c$ is some constant.

Comment: @Winther Will I ever had an index that is repeated more than twice?

Comment: No that should never happen (well we can have terms like $(a_i - b_i)(a_i - b_i)$ however when expanded out this is $a_ia_i + b_ib_i -2a_ib_i$ where no indices are repeated more than twice in the individual terms)

Comment: @Winther is this legal $ P^ir_i = \delta^{ij}P_jr_i = P_jr^j $?

Comment: I must have misread your comment. What you have written is correct: $P^ir_i = P_jr^j$.

Comment: I should also note that in my comments above I was pretty sloppy with the placement of the indices. For consistency one should have one upper and one lower index when summing: $a_ia^i$ not $a_ia_i$. For this problem it it's not really a problem as "$P_i = P^i$", however it's a good habit to do it consistently (as you have done).

Comment: @Winther I'll keep that in mind. I've been able to put the equation into the form $P_aQ^a - 3\frac{P_vQ^n(r^vr_n)}{r^2}$, which looks similar to what you expected. Now to just mind my P's and Q's ;)

Comment: That is the correct answer for the expression. If you now change the label $v$ to $a$ in the second expression and write $Q^a = \delta^a_n Q^n$ in the first expression you will be able to write this on the form $P_a [T^a_n ]Q^n$ which allows you to extract $T^a_n$. btw if you want you can write your own answer here. Then the question is officially answered and it can be useful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help of @Winther, the solution is as follows:

$$
U = \frac{1}{r^3}\left(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{Q} - \dfrac{3(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{r})(\vec{Q}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^2}\right) \equiv \frac{1}{r^3}P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
\vec{P}\cdot\vec{Q} - \dfrac{3(\vec{P}\cdot\vec{r})(\vec{Q}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
$$
$$
P^ke_kQ_le^l- \dfrac{3(P^ie_ir_je^j)(Q^ne_nr_me^m)}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P^lQ_l- \dfrac{3(P^ir_i)(Q^nr_n)}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P^lQ_l- \dfrac{3(\delta^{iv}P_vr_i)(Q^nr_n)}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P^lQ_l- \dfrac{3P_vQ^n(r^vr_n)}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_aQ^a- \dfrac{3P_aQ^n(r^ar_n)}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_a\delta^a_nQ^n- \dfrac{3P_a(r^ar_n)Q^n}{r^2} = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_a\left(\delta^a_n - 3\dfrac{(r^ar_n)}{r^2}\right)Q^n = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
P_a\left[T_n^a\right]Q^n = P_iT_j^iQ^j\\
$$
$$
\boxed{T_j^i = \delta^i_j - 3\dfrac{r^ir_j}{r^2}}
$$